# How can I route traffic to another domain without changing the browser URL?

Tags: nginx

I want to route the traffic from a domain to another domain(with different subpath) without change the URL in brower using Nginx.
For example, I /app/example/  ---> https://another_domain.com:443/dev/app/
I have tried using

```
location /app/example/ {
    proxy_pass https://another_domain.com:443/dev/app/;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

But the URL in the browser will be changed to "https://another_domain.com:443/dev/app/" when I try to access "/app/example", that it not what I want.

I have also tried using the same subpath:

```
 location /app/example/ {
    proxy_pass https://another_domain.com:443;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

The URL in the browser does not change, but my requirement is to route traffic to another subpath in another domain.

Could anybody help me? How can I route the traffic to another subpath of another domain using Nginx without changing the URL in browser?

Answer (score 1):

To get this working correctly, you'll need to own and control the responses of the destination server to ensure the HTML sub-resources (images, CSS, JS) work correctly.  [As Brad said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408096/how-can-i-route-traffic-to-another-domainwith-different-subpath-without-change#answer-70408107), it's difficult to proxy third-party sites you don't control.  Typically, the relative `href` and `src` tags in the destination HTML response need to use absolute URLs of the destination server URL.

When done correctly using absolute URLs, this works:

```
##
##  ✅ https://example.com/proxy-absolute
##  ❌ https://example.com/proxy-relative
##
location ~ ^/proxy-(absolute|relative)$ {
  proxy_pass https://batman.dev/static/70408096/$1.html;
}
```

From these third-party examples, you can see how Google search is missing sub-resources.  Bing detects the proxy outright and redirects to its own domain.

```
##
##  https://example.com/google-search/apple
##
location ~ ^/google-search/([^/]+) {
  proxy_pass https://www.google.com/search?q=$1;  
}

##
##  https://example.com/bing-search/apple
##
location ~ ^/bing-search/([^/]+) {
  proxy_pass https://bing.com/search?q=$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Proxying isn't a good solution, as you'll likely break some resources on the page by serving them from a different domain.

The best you can do is create a page that has nothing but an iframe, which loads the other site.  And, this only works if the target site doesn't have frame busting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. We had thought of using iframe but, someone said it might break the style of the nested page. Anyhow, thanks

Comment: @KaojunSong No problem!  If you find this answer useful, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as "solved".

Comment: @KaojunSong If you use `<iframe>`, it won't break the style.